# Are there any good ways of separating movement options in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

there!
I'm sorry if the title sounds confusing, couldn't find any better way to title it.
I want my game to have a lot of different movement option for the player(like: wall run, grappling, double jump, teleportation, etc.) It already has a few, so I've decided its time to separate them(by "separating" I mean blocking one movement option, while player uses the other (e.g.: player shouldn't be able to teleport, while wall running)). I've tried implementing a state machine, but it required major changes in my scripts and overall was beyond my skills. So I was wondering if there are any simpler ways of doing it (without dozen if/else statement, of course)

Comment: The most common solution to reducing big `if-else` or `switch` blocks in an object oriented language is to use polymorphism. You could make an `IMovement` interface, with a `Move()` method, and create different implementations for each type of movement, e.g. create a `GrappleMovement`. Have a look at the [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) for more details. This is a very open-ended question, and there's not going to be a single correct answer, so I'm voting to close